# LibJingle pcp always gives me "Bus error: 10"

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I am trying to play with the sample application 'pcp' to send file between different directory.
The step is as following:

1. run receiver by /tmp/test1/pcp account@gmail.com
2. run sender by /tmp/test2/pcp account@gmail.com a.txt account@gmail.com/(full JID):a.txt

I always gets the "bus error:10" in the receiver side when running the sender.

I also tried to run in --verbose option and got more info. as follows:

```
[173:339] TunnelSessionClientBase::OnSessionCreate: received=1
[173:342] Session:12662708465646360189 Old state:STATE_INIT New state:STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE Type:http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel Transport:http://www.google.com/transport/p2p
[173:343] TunnelSession::OnSessionState(Session::STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE)
IncomingTunnel from theeraphol.wat@gmail.com/pcpC89CFD53: recv:b.txt
[173:343] Session:12662708465646360189 Old state:STATE_RECEIVEDINITIATE New state:STATE_SENTACCEPT Type:http://www.google.com/talk/securetunnel Transport:http://www.google.com/transport/p2p
[173:343] TunnelSession::OnSessionState(Session::STATE_SENTACCEPT)
Bus error: 10
```

What am I doing wrong?